# BeautifulSoup: Get the HTML Code of Modal Footer

Tags: python, html-parsing, edgar

I'm new to Web scraping in Python and try to scrape all htm document-links from an SEC Edgar full-text search. I can see the link in the Modal Footer, but BeautifulSoup won't parse the href Element with the link.

Is there an easy solution to parse the links of the documents?

[image: Snapshot of the Link in the HTML Code on the Website]

```py
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/q=ex10&category=custom&forms=10-K%252C10-Q%252C8-K'
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    
for a in soup.find_all(id = "open-file"):
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

That data is loaded dynamically using javascript. There is a lot of information about scraping this kind of page ([see one of many examples here](https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/web-scraping-discovering-hidden-apis/)); in this case, the following should get you there:

```
import requests
import json
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',   
}

data = '{"q":"ex10","category":"custom","forms":["10-K","10-Q","8-K"],"startdt":"2020-10-08","enddt":"2021-10-08"}'
#obvioulsy, you need to change "startdt" and "enddt" as necessary
response = requests.post('https://efts.sec.gov/LATEST/search-index', headers=headers, data=data)
```

The response is in json format. Your urls are hidden in there:

```
data = json.loads(response.text)
hits = data['hits']['hits']
for hit in hits:
    cik = hit['_source']['ciks'][0]
    file_data = hit['_id'].split(":")
    filing = file_data[0].replace('-','')
    file_name = file_data[1]
    url = f'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/{cik}/{filing}/{file_name}'
    print(url)
```

Output:

```
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001372183/000158069520000415/ex10-5.htm
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001372183/000138713120009670/ex10-5.htm
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001540615/000154061520000006/ex10.htm
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001552189/000165495421004948/ex10-1.htm
```

etc.